# Recharts - Pass value of dataKey to child component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, recharts

How can i pass the value of a dataKey to another component? I have a line chart with a custom dot, this dots needs a value from the data. How can i pass the value of a datakey to it?

```
const data = [
    { name: 'abc', value: '1' },
    { name: 'cde', value: '2',},
    { name: 'fgh', value: '3' }
    ...
];

<LineChart data={data} margin={{ right: 50, left: 50 }}>
    <Tooltip />
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="value" stroke="black" strokeWidth="1px" dot={<CustomDot name={[[[name dataKey]]]} />} />
</LineChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [this example](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomizedDotLineChart) provided by Recharts, you'll see that if you pass in a React element to the `dot` property of `Line`, it will have the following properties automatically: `cx, cy, stroke, payload, value`, where `cx` and `cy` are the coordinates that you need to draw the dot and `value` is the value you are looking for.

You can play around with their JSFiddle example to see how it all works:  https://jsfiddle.net/ps1a6jeu/5/

Comment: I think he is talking about passing more than one value to the component. In the example we pass one value i.e. `value` and use it compute `smileys` based on that but what if the data is previously mapped in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but you are looking to pass two properties into the `Line` component so you can use the other to make `dynamic` dots. As per my understanding, this use case is not covered as the child components only see what has been passed to the parent as `dataKey` and `dataKey` only accepts a `string` and `number`, so you cannot pass an `object`.

You can achieve the same functionality using `LabelList`. I forked the `CustomziedDot` example and made some changes

https://jsfiddle.net/hs86kb97/11/

See if this helps.